# Vector space$V$ is direct sum of eigenspaces of $\phi$ when $\phi $ is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, generalized-eigenvector

This seems a simple statement but if $\phi \in \text{End}_K (V)$ is diagonalisable then I am trying to show that $$V=V_{\lambda_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus V_{\lambda_n} $$  where $\lambda_1 ,\ldots, \lambda_n$ are the distinct eigenvalues (though we may have $r < \dim (V) ) $.

I know that in general we have a direct sum into generalised eigenspaces but this above is a stronger result when $\phi $ is diagonalisable.

Comment: Diagonalizable means there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors. $V_{\lambda_i}$ will be the span of the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

Comment: What is your definition of diagonalizable here? Usually, diagonalizable means pretty much exactly what you are trying to show.

Comment: My problem was showing that in this basis of eigenvectors, the eigenvectors in the basis with eigenvalue $\lambda $ span $V_{\lambda } $